# Remove pluses, dashes, colons using REGEX and C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove these occurrences in a document using REGEX and C#. They are:
+-------------+ (there can be any number of dashes between plus signs)
:             : (there can be any number of spaces between colons)
I cannot remove standalone dashes or semi-colons since they may come after Name: or Address: and are needed. I cannot remove a colon between words with a space on either side. The colon with spaces creates formatting that I need to remove. The plus with dashes in-between creates a line or part of a box that I need to remove.

Basically, I need to remove all dashes with pluses at the ends, including removing the pluses. I also need to remove all spaces with colons at each end, including removing the colon. All other pluses and colons need to remain. This is a medical text file so I need to be careful. I do not have any code to show you since nothing I have tried has come close to working.
Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: "I do not have any code to show you since nothing I have tried has come close to working." You can still show what you tried even if it didn't come close to working. It would still show your thought processes and help us to find out any unstated requirements.

Comment: Try learning regex's. I use [RadDesigns](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/) with a [Regex cheatsheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression with [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx):

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\+-+\+|: +:", "");
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/rKaG7)

Comment: Works great...Thanks. I also need to remove the colons on each end of a line without removing those bteween. Here is a lne of text     :Name: NOTREALPERSON, TESTStudy Date: 08/15/2012 06:01 PMBP: 120/100 mmHg : I need to remove the colon before Name and after mmHg but not after Name, Date, or PMBP.

Comment: if you want a fast answer, please post a new question. I don't have time right now.